# Comparing sets in Java; operation does not work as expected in both directions

Tags: java, set, removeall

Having created two sets of different sizes, but with some common elements, the intention is to identify the elements in each set that make it different from the other set.  The Set class in Java seemed to have a good method: removeAll.  I did the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Create a new set
        Set<String> mySet1 = new HashSet();

        // Add elements
        mySet1.add("1");
        mySet1.add("2");
        mySet1.add("4");
        mySet1.add("5");
        mySet1.add("6");
        mySet1.add("7");

        // Print the elements of the Set1
        System.out.println("mySet1: " + mySet1);

        // Create a new set
        Set<String> mySet2 = new HashSet();

        // Add elements
        mySet2.add("1");
        mySet2.add("2");
        mySet2.add("3");
        mySet2.add("5");
        mySet2.add("6");
        mySet2.add("7");
        mySet2.add("8");

        System.out.println("mySet2: " + mySet2);

        // Compare the two sets
        System.out.println("MySet1 matches mySet2: " + mySet1.equals(mySet2));

        // Remove all elements of mySet2 from mySet1
        Set<String> deletions = mySet1;
        deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
        System.out.println("deletions: " + deletions);

        // Remove all elements of mySet1 from mySet2
        Set<String> updates = mySet2;
        updates.removeAll(mySet1);
        System.out.println("updates: " + updates);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
mySet1: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
mySet2: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
MySet1 matches mySet2: false
deletions: [4]
updates: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Why isn't the result for 'updates' `[3,8]`?

Comment: You're mutating the original sets.  You need to create copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deletions` refers to the same Set as `mySet1` due to the `Set<String> deletions = mySet1` assignment. Therefore `deletions.removeAll` removed elements from the original Set `mySet1`, so the second `removeAll` received a Set that contains just "4".

You should create copies of the original Sets in order not to mutate `mySet1` and `mySet2` :

```
Set<String> deletions = new HashSet<>(mySet1); // create a copy of mySet1
deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
System.out.println("deletions: " + deletions);

// Remove all elements of mySet1 from mySet2
Set<String> updates = new HashSet<>(mySet2); // create a copy of mySet2
updates.removeAll(mySet1);
System.out.println("updates: " + updates);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<String> deletions = mySet1;
deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
```

You have just removed all of `mySet2` from `mySet1`. Assigning another variable to an object does not copy the object. You can copy it easily enough with `HashSet`'s constructor:

```
Set<String> deletions = new HashSet<String>(mySet1);
deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation that you're performing here is called [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).  You're looking for the union of elements that are in A - B and B - A (with set subtraction).

Your code overwrites your original sets, so it should be a simple matter of creating new `Set`s ensure that the operations don't mutate anything.

```
// Remove all elements of mySet2 from mySet1
Set<String> deletions = new HashSet<>(mySet1);
deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
System.out.println("deletions: " + deletions);

// Remove all elements of mySet1 from mySet2
Set<String> updates = new HashSet<>(mySet2);
updates.removeAll(mySet1);
System.out.println("updates: " + updates);
```

Alternatively, [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a [Sets utility](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained%23Sets) which has a [`symmetricDifference`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html%23symmetricDifference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) method:

```
// prints the numbers 4, 3, and 8 in no guaranteed order
System.out.println(Sets.symmetricDifference(mySet1, mySet2));
```

Comment: Definitely use Guava's `Sets` class; no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line, you have assigned the deletions reference the mySet1 object, so now both deletions and mySet1 are pointing to same object.
    Set deletions = mySet1;
Later you have removed all elements of deletions that are contained in mySet2, which leaves deletions with just one element 4. Since, mySet1 and deletions both are pointing to same object, so this means mySet1 also has one element left which is 4.
When you try to remove all elements of mySet1 from mySet2, it just tries to remove the element 4 from the mySet2. Hence the output.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code:

```
Set<String> deletions = mySet1;
```

You have created one more reference to the same set.Both deletions and mySet1
are now 2 variables that point to the same set.With the following line, you have changed the contents of this set.

```
deletions.removeAll(mySet2);
```

Effectively,now mySet1 will also contain only elements that deletions contain since both of them are just references that point to the same set. Thats why with the following code you got the unexpected result

```
updates.removeAll(mySet1);
```

You need to create a separate copy of the sets so that you can have the results you expect.You can do this by following:

```
Set<String> deletions = new HashSet<>(mySet1);
```